# Azure VM hosted APIs should be accessible to azure APIM only

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I have my APIs hosted on a azure windows virtual machine. I want that these APIs should be privately consumed by API management. If I make VM and APIM in same VNET and configure APIM as internal then my APIs exposed by APIM will not be accessed by public web app and If I make my APIM external then my developer portal will be publically accessible, which I dont want.

Is there any policy or outbound/inbound rule that can be configured so that APIs from VM, and APIM developer portal is not publically accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet), if you select **internal** option in the virtual network of API Management services,

> the API Management gateway and developer portal are accessible only
> from within the virtual network via an internal load balancer. The
> gateway can access resources within the virtual network.

In this case, you can deploy your APIM into a vNet following the [common network configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-common-network-configuration-issues)---dns and NSG rules. The API hosted VM should be able to resolve the develop portal with a private IP address.

Comment: Thank you, Nancy! I will try this. I hope adding APIM as internal will not block my web app to access the APIs from APIM. My web app will be publicly accessible.

Comment: You also could make azure web app outbound  from the same vNet with [vNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).